# std::async with gcc 7.2 need pthread link option

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stdasync, gcc7

The following code need pthread link option to compile, and i don't understand why. Do you have any idea?

I'm using gcc 7.2.0

```
#include <future>

int sum = 0;

void func()
{
   for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
      sum +=i;
}

int main()
{
    std::future<void> f =  std::async(std::launch::async, func);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

provides the following error

```
/tmp/ccoEkyeZ.o: dans la fonction « std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)()> >, void>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)()> >&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)()> >, void>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)()> >&&)::{lambda()#1}&&) »:
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJPFvvEEEEEvEC4EOS8_EUlvE_JEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJPFvvEEEEEvEC4EOS8_EUlvE_JEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x30): référence indéfinie vers « pthread_create »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

while using

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lpthread
```

has no issue.

is this normal? do i missing something? my code doesn't have pthread_create somewhere

Comment: Because your C++ Standard Library implementation uses pthreads.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, yes i suspect that, but this flag shoudn't be managed in the standard library implementation?

Comment: Ideally, yes, and it is in the MinGW GCC implementations I use - which one are you using? But it doesn't have to be - the C++ Standard says nothing about how compiling and linking should be managed on specific platforms.

Comment: i'm using gcc Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It is recommended to use the switch `-pthread` rather than the linker flag `-lpthread`.

Comment: fwiw, currently `GCC` also implements the *filesystem* `TS` as a separate library too, requiring `-lstdc++fs` for the linker

Answer (score 4):

*Your* code may not have a `pthread_create` in it but just think for a minute what asynchronous processing actually entails.

It's a near certainty that an asynchronous function will be run in a separate thread so that it can, well, run asynchronously with the main code. That should be evident by the fact your error message contains the text `std::thread` several times.

And, in your environment, it seems that `std::thread` uses pthreads under the covers.

This is really no different to your code containing `cout << someInt` and it possibly complaining about a missing `itoa`-like function for doing integer-to-string conversions. Your setup would probably be seriously broken if it included streams but no standard conversions but the *concept* is still valid.

The executable must have access to all the stuff you explicitly call, *plus* all of the other dependencies that entails.

---

For what it's worth, this *is* covered (albeit vaguely) in the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html) (my emphasis):

> When you link a multithreaded application, you will probably need to add a library or flag to `g++`. This is a very non-standardized area of GCC across ports. Some ports support a special flag (the spelling isn't even standardized yet) to add all required macros to a compilation (if any such flags are required then you must provide the flag for all compilations not just linking) and link-library additions and/or replacements at link time. The documentation is weak.
>
> ***On several targets (including GNU/Linux, Solaris and various BSDs) `-pthread` is honored.***

Comment: i do agree, and understand that, my question was most on the fact that this flag should be managed by the stl implementation

Comment: @bonpiedlaroute Well, `std::thread` doesn't do this either, so it's a moot point if it's not addressed at the root. Use a build system like CMake and it will do it automatically for you using `find_packages(Threads)` and linking to `${CMAKE_THREADS_LIB_INIT}`. Not ideal, but it's reality.